# Source for Chazon Ish on What defines a Lamdan

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, chazon-ish

I recently read [an article](http://matzav.com/finding-the-right-words) and the author wrote the following:

"The Chazon Ish described the true lamdan as “someone who spends three hours preparing to deliver a five-minute shiur, and when he is done, the people who attended say, ‘What’s the big deal? What he said is so simple."

Where, if it's published, can I find the source for this?

Comment: You could always try asking [the author](http://rabbipinchoslipschutz.blogspot.com/) what his source was.

Comment: Try looking in Orchos Drabbeinu maybe

Comment: @sam I don't have that Sefer. If you do, could you check?

Comment: If I get a chance its five volumes